# Laplace Transform of $\cos \sqrt t$

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, laplace-transform

Please provide me with a solution(with complete steps using power series only)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I dont want answer but the solution with steps, using power series of cos x

Comment: This is not a homework site and no one is going to spoon feed you the answer here. Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xt} \cos \sqrt t dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xt} \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{t^k }}{{(2k)!}}} } \right)dt}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k)!}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xt} t^k dt} } 
\\
 = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k)!}}\frac{{k!}}{{x^{k + 1} }}}  = \frac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{k!}}{{(2k)!}}\frac{1}{{x^k }}} =
\frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{x}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\Gamma \left( {k + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}\left( { - \frac{1}{{4x}}} \right)^k } \\ = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{{2x\sqrt x }}\exp \left( { - \frac{1}{{4x}}} \right)\operatorname{erfi}\left( {\frac{1}{{2\sqrt x }}} \right).
$$
Here $\operatorname{erfi}$ denotes the imaginary error function. It is an entire function.

Comment: https://ibb.co/FBHj5ZV

Can you please simply the solution the way it is solved for sin under root t, in the link It might help..please..Your provided solution is correct but hard for a  16 year old like me to understand